# Google Animation - How do they create the png sprite

Tags: animation, sprite

I understand that apart from when Google uses canvas in its animations, they use a big png sprite and move it using JS to create the animation.

I can also see that there are tools such as http://spriteme.org/ that will create the sprite from a bunch of pngs.

What I'd like to know is how would you go about creating those pngs in the first place? I could imagine that creating each sprite in photoshop would be a pain. For example you wouldn't be able to see what the animation feels like along the way.

Plus editing it once its saved would be a pain as you'd have a bunch of pngs or the original photoshop document, and would need to re-export the individual pngs and then re-sprite it.

Is this where a tool like adobe edge animation does the heavy lifting?

as ever - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I use Flash to make the anim, export the animation in png, and generate the sprite with spritegenerator.exe http://spritegenerator.codeplex.com/releases/view/52139

Comment: thanks for this. I'll check it out the next time. In the latest flash version there is actually a export things as sprites but this might be able to do a bit more.